# Is there any redis input plugin supports “lpop” command?

Tags: redis, logstash

The last time I checked the logstash doc said that the official redis input plugin uses "blpop" command to get messages from redis. (Correct me if I'm wrong.)

However, our redis cluster does not allow command "blpop". So I'm wondering is there any redis input plugin that uses "lpop" command? Or do I have to write my own.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't any so I wrote my own version of logstash redis input plugin that using "lpop" instead of "blpop" (in the official logstash redis input plugin) [here](https://github.com/MichaelScofield/logstash-input-redis_poller)